# Vue + Element UI: (el-select) select an object option and pass value to multiple property

Tags: vue.js, select, element-ui

In Vue2 I got an array of objects

**OptionsArr**

```
[
 {
  name: "apple" ,
  price: 200
 },
 {
  name: "orange" ,
  price: 150
 }
]
```

and an el-select:

```
<el-select
   v-model="item.name"
 >
   <el-option
     v-for="(option,index) in OptionsArr"
     :key="index"
     :label="option.name"
     :value="option.name"
   >
    {{option.name}}
   </el-option>
```

data **item**

```
{
 name:"",
 price:undefined,
 count:2
}
```

How could I save both name and price to item when select an option?
For example, when I choose the option apple, the item should be

```
{
 name:"apple",
 price:200,
 count:2
}
```

I tried to use :value.sync instead of v-model but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change **v-model** of **el-select** to **item**

change **:value** of **el-option** to **option**

and add prop **value-key** to **el-select** too(like **name** if your item.name is unique)

Comment: To allow creating new options there are **filterable**,**allow-create** and **@blur="selectBlur($event, 'name')"** in **el-select**, and a method `selectBlur(e){ if(e.target.value){ this.$set(this.owner, 'name', e.target.value); }
}`, after those changes it couldn't add new options anymore, what should I modify?

Comment: Now I input "something" and the item array be like `["something"]` and I want to make it `[{name:"something", price0:, count:0}]`